# kinect and turtlebot and xbox

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
It seems if I want to DIY to put kinect purchased together with a xbox on turtlebox, I have to modify the original kinect which involves cutting the power cable of kinect. Can the modified kinect be still used with xbox? Anyone has done this?

Thanks

Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43830/kinect-and-turtlebot-and-xbox/) by [Jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3171/jackie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out Pgs. 17-20 of our [TurtleBot hardware manual](http://clearpathrobotics.com/downloads/TurtleBot-UserManual.pdf). It assumes that you've got the AC power adapter for your Kinect (which IIRC is optional). If you've got the adapter, you can modify it in a way where you can put it back together (shown in the manual). If you don't have the adapter, you'll need to get one.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3171/jackie/) on 2012-09-14**:
Thanks Ryan. Very detailed instruction.

**Comment by [cosmoharrigan](https://answers.ros.org/users/8501/cosmoharrigan/) on 2013-11-06**:
The link provided does not work anymore. The TurtleBot hardware documentation is still available in this archive hosted by ROS:
http://download.ros.org/downloads/turtlebot/TurtleBot-Hardware-2011-07-23.zip